# Migrating from 'file sharing' paradigm in StarTeam to a DVCS like GIT?

Tags: git, visual-sourcesafe, dvcs, starteam

StarTeam has file sharing between views.  Basically a view in StarTeam can share individual files from other views.  It can then branch the files as well. Are there ways to migrate views in StarTeam that share hundreds of files with each other? Anyone have experience with this?  Assuming that the only solution is to convert one StarTeam 'view' to one repository say in GIT, are there strategies to still allow sharing of files amongst multiple repositories in say GIT?

Sean

Answer (score 2):

[Git User's Manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#submodules):

> Git's submodule support allows a
>   repository to contain, as a
>   subdirectory, a checkout of an
>   external project. Submodules maintain
>   their own identity; the submodule
>   support just stores the submodule
>   repository location and commit ID, so
>   other developers who clone the
>   containing project ("superproject")
>   can easily clone all the submodules at
>   the same revision. Partial checkouts
>   of the superproject are possible: you
>   can tell Git to clone none, some or
>   all of the submodules.

[git-submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) command initialize, update or inspect submodules.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know StarTeam, but what you're describing sounds like they could be long-standing branches in Git.

Suppose you wanted to have independent releases for some specialized hardware A & B, in addition to your ongoing development: you can keep separate branches for A releases & B releases, with the shared files that you are developing on the `master` branch. Then you only merge from `master` into your specialized branches, and never from them into `master`.

This is often simpler than keeping separate repos or sub-modules, because Git is tracking trees of trees if file changes, rather than individual files.